# Enabling the "Render Layers as a Group" option in QGIS through python

Tags: python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, group-layer, transparency-opacity

I have written a simple python function that loads several existing shapefile layers into a new group in QGIS 3.28. I would like to extend this function to also automatically enable the "Render Layers as a Group" option for this group and apply an opacity of 25%, but I can't see how this is done in the API documentation.

Edit - Here's a snippet of the code:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
root = project.layerTreeRoot()
grpSEPASurfaceWater = root.insertGroup(index, 'SEPA Flood Map | Surface Water')
QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinition([path to layer being loaded], project, grpSEPASurfaceWater)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just missing a few lines.

```python
project = QgsProject.instance()
root = project.layerTreeRoot()
grpSEPASurfaceWater = root.insertGroup(index, 'SEPA Flood Map | Surface Water')

# Set Render Layers as a Group
group_options = QgsGroupLayer.LayerOptions(project.transformContext())
grpSEPASurfaceWaterLayer = grpSEPASurfaceWater.convertToGroupLayer(group_options)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(grpSEPASurfaceWaterLayer , False)

# Set opacity of group
grpSEPASurfaceWaterLayer.setOpacity(0.25)

QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinition([path to layer being loaded], project, grpSEPASurfaceWater)
```

An other way to do it

```python
project = QgsProject.instance()
root = project.layerTreeRoot()
grpSEPASurfaceWater = root.insertGroup(index, 'SEPA Flood Map | Surface Water')

# Set Render Layers as a Group
group_options = QgsGroupLayer.LayerOptions(project.transformContext())
group_layer = QgsGroupLayer('group layer', group_options)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(group_layer, False)
grpSEPASurfaceWater.setGroupLayer(group_layer)

# Set opacity of group
grpSEPASurfaceWater.groupLayer().setOpacity(0.25)

QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinition([path to layer being loaded], project, grpSEPASurfaceWater)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to be working for me. I think I've pinpointed the issue to the convertToGroupLayer line. When I run some of the commands one by one in the python console, I can see that I've got a QgsLayerTreeGroup called grpSEPASurfaceWater, but then the convertToGroupLayer line doesn't result in a QgsGroup called grpSEPASurfaceWaterLayer as I'd expect. It shows "None".

Comment: Hum weird, when I run this, the group stays named "grpSEPASurfaceWater" it doesn't spawn another group and it sets "renderer layers as a group" checkbox

Comment: `grpSEPASurfaceWaterLayer = grpSEPASurfaceWater.convertToGroupLayer(group_options)` Doesn't create a new group it set up the current as a rendering layer and returns a `QgsGroupLayer` which inherits from `QgsMapLayer` giving you access to its functions

Comment: I added the `QgsProject.instance.addMapLayer()` since there were ownership issues without it

Comment: The "other way" seems to have worked for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This should probably use `project.transformContext()`, not a new `QgsCoordinateTransformContext()`.